# How to add a new layer to an existing docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an image that is provided to us by a vendor, and I would like to add some company certificates into the image.

I am not sure what the original image includes, but assuming there were some commands like EXPOSE, etc used in the previous image, when adding a new layer will I have to re-EXPOSE, etc.? Or will everything in the previous image be intact?

Comment: When you create a new image based on an existing image, you start with all the configuration (`EXPOSE`, `ENV`, `ENTRYPOINT`, `CMD`, etc) from the original image. You don't have to re-define it.